# Show loading spinner with minimum time

Tags: reactjs, axios

I implemented a page loader during axios request but it shows for a very short time. How to show it for a minimum 2 seconds or with fancy fade in react? Is it possible?

```
const Loader = () => (
    <div class="divLoader">
      Loading..
    </div>
 );

class dashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            data: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
            axios.get("http://localhost:8080/user/dashboard")
            .then((res) => {
                const data = res.data;
                this.setState({ data, loading: false })

            }, (error) => {
                this.handleLogout();
                console.log("dasboard ERR");
            });


    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-xxl">
                 {this.state.loading ? <Loader /> : <Content />}
             </div>
    )};

}
```

Comment: Basically your loading state watches for the API response and your response might have been coming very soon. Adding a timeout is a bad solution as it will become independent of API response. Even if it fails or in pending state the ```loading ```state will becoming ```false```. So, better use a new state with default as false and make that true after 2 second and render your component by comparing both of your states. Or simply use ```setTimeout```  to set state after API success rather than directly setting the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to design what you're trying to achieve by considering two things.

If your API response time is very low then keep the loader for an extra few times by applying a `setTimeOut`. But here you've got another thing to keep in mind. What if your API response time takes a moderate time which is enough as the lifetime of a loader to show? In this case, you may not keep your loader for extra time as that will make the visitors bored. So, what you have to do is keeping a timer. Say, `x`(in milisecond) is the least time you want to show the loader. If elapsed time (or the time API is taking to respond i.e., the loader is live for this time) is greater than `x` then you're done. If not then `setTimeOut` for (`x - elapsed time`).

Comment: You really should share a code sample of your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your loader is showing for very short time is because your
fetch is taking too little time to gather data and changing the state of loader to false, which causes re-rendering and shows content instead of the loader.

```
componentDidMount() {
         axios.get("http://localhost:8080/user/dashboard")
         .then((res) => {
             const data = res.data;
         //     this.setState({ data, loading: false })
          setTimeout(() => {
              this.setState({data, loading: false })
         }, 2000)
    
         }, (error) => {
             this.handleLogout();
             console.log("dasboard ERR");
         });
    
    
    }
```

what I am doing here is using setTimeOut which will wait for 2000ms or 2s then it will change the update the `state -> loading` to `false` and hence the content will be shown after exact 2 seconds.

Comment: With this approach, if the API response already takes 2s, The loading spinner would be visible for 4s

Answer (score 1):

```
const delay = 1000; //1s
let setTimeoutInstance;

export const Loader = ({ loading, children }) => {
  const [isExpired, setIsExpired] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) {
      setIsExpired(false);

      if (setTimeoutInstance) {
        clearTimeout(setTimeoutInstance);
      }
      setTimeoutInstance = setTimeout(() => {
        setIsExpired(true);
      }, delay);
    }
  }, [loading]);

  if (!isExpired) {
    return 'Loading . . .';
  }

  return children;
};
```

You can use it like this:

```
<Loader loading={this.state.loading}>
// content
</Loader>
```